# is the following a topological invariant

Tags: general-topology

I am studying a basic course in homology theory from wallace's book.I am really confused when he says"the maximum no of closed curves along which a surface may be cut without dividing it into two or more disjoint parts is a topological invariant".How do i prove this?

any help would be appericiated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f : X \to Y$ an homeomorphism between surfaces. If $\gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_n$ are such curves on $X$, then $f(\gamma_1), \dots, f(\gamma_n)$ are such curves on $Y$, as $Y \backslash (f(\gamma_1) \cup \dots, f(\gamma_n)) \cong X \backslash (\gamma_1 \cup \dots \cup \gamma_n)$ which is connected. So if $l(X)$ denotes the number of noh-separating curves on $X$, we have $l(X) \leq l(Y)$. By a similar argument $l(Y) \leq l(X)$ so $l(X) = l(Y)$.

Comment: :thanks for your answer...how is l(x)<l(y)

Comment: You're welcome ! We don't have $l(X)  < l(Y)$ but $l(X) \leq l(Y)$ (this is important as in fact equality occurs). This is because I showed that $n \leq l(X) \Rightarrow n \leq l(Y)$ for all $n$ so taking $n = l(X)$ gives the result.

Comment: thanks for the clarification...